# zend helper Db_NoRecordExists for multiple table check

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I want to check mobile number uniqueness in my two table ..I have added this code but It checking only second one...Is it any other way to validated this in form..

```
$this->addElement('text', 'mobilenumber', array(`enter code here`
            'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
            'validators' => array`enter code here`(
                                array('Db_NoRecordExists', true, array('table' => 'beroe_user', 'field' => 'mobilenumber', 'messages' => array(
                                   'recordFound' => 'mobilenumber already exists'
                                ))),
                                array('Db_NoRecordExists', true, array('table' => 'beroe_user', 'field' => 'mobilenumber', 'messages' => array(
                                   'recordFound' => 'admin already exists'
                                ))),
            ),
            // 'required'   => true,
            'label'      => 'Phone ',
            'maxlength'  => '15'
        ));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is because when we add same validator to an element multiple times the former will be overridden. Check class Zend_Form_Element, addValidator() line 1153
You can create a custom validators as you need. It would be the best thing to do.